# How to add datasource to WAS 8.5 without Admin Console

Tags: xml, datasource, websphere-8

Long story short, I don't have the Websphere admin console, I'm not able to install the admin console or any other server GUI aid, and the great forces above who designate what gets pushed to my machine won't allow me to aquire the admin console in the forseeable future.

With that said, **how do I add a new datasource to my Websphere server without the Admin Console?**

My only idea was to go dig around in the xml files. I'm adding a JDBC datasource, and it looks like others of its kin are stored in {SERVER}/nodes/{NODE}/servers/{SERVER NAME}/resources.xml The inside of it looks like--

```
 <factories xmi:type="resources.jdbc:DataSource" xmi:id="DataSource_1412375554645" name="Data Source Name" jndiName="jdbc/mssql/datasource" description="MS SQL DS" ... (etc.)>
      <propertySet xmi:id="J2EEResourcePropertySet_1412375554650">
        <resourceProperties xmi:id="J2EEResourceProperty_1412375554650" name="applicationIntent" type="java.lang.String" value="" ... (etc.) />
        <resourceProperties xmi:id="J2EEResourceProperty_1412375554651" name="applicationName" type="java.lang.String" value="WebSphere Application Server" ... (etc.) />
```

... And so on for every property in the defined datasource. I can't just copy-paste an xml chunk and change the values to what I'd like my datasource to have, since the xmi ids all appear to be unique strings. I attempted this anyway, by slightly editing the numbers inserted at the end of the xmi id so they would be unique/sequential, and it still gave me the `DATASOURCE_NAME not found.` error. That's all I've tried so far.

Is there a set series of files I'm supposed to edit in order to add a datasource? Are there any other tools that WAS 8.5 comes with that allows me to add a datasource? Is it even possible to do this without the admin console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't do it by hand, it is too error prone. If you don't have admin console do it via wsadmin scripting.

You will need first to define JDBC provider:

For details - see [Configuring a JDBC provider using wsadmin](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/txml_configjdbc.html?lang=en)

> AdminTask.createJDBCProvider (['-interactive'])

then configure the data source - see [Configuring new data sources using wsadmin](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/txml_configdatasource.html?lang=en)

> AdminTask.createDatasource (['-interactive'])

As other option you can use property file based configuration. Especially if you have similar environment already configured. The full property files are to long to paste it here but well documented in the following links:

- [Working with JDBC provider properties files](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/txml_config_prop_jdbcprovider.html?lang=en)
- [Working with data source properties files](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/txml_config_prop_jdbcprovider_ds.html?lang=en)

If you have similar environment, you can export configuration from one environment and import to the other:

- [Extracting properties files using wsadmin scripting](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/txml_7extractprops.html?lang=en)
- [Applying portable properties files across multiple environments](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/txml_portable_prop.html?lang=en)